# Disable HTML encoding of attribute values in TagBuilder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, tagbuilder

I'm using MVC and I've created a HtmlHelper extension function ImageLink. This function uses two TagBuilder objects to build an HTML image link (like `<a><img/></a>`).

It works fine, but now I have a page on which the action for the image button should first be confirmed. So, I added an onclick attribute with "javascript: return confirm('confirm me');" as the onclick code.

This renders as: onclick="javascript:return confirm('confirm me');"

I though this wouldn't work, but it does. But now when we enter:

"javascript: return confirm('confirm me\r\nnewline');"

this renders as:

onclick="javascript:return confirm('confirm me
newline');"

which doesn't work.

I'd prefer for the TagBuilder not to encode anything at all and just let me take care of it. But since it does, I'm now looking for a way to get this working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backslash (\) is a special character in C# strings so you just have to escape it as you would normally do in any other situation when you want it to appear in the final string.

```
tag.MergeAttribute("onclick", "return confirm('first line\\n\\nsecond line');");
```

Comment: Quoting H. Simpson: DOH! Thanks!